# Runtime configuration of a project without an IDE

Tags: java, command-line

Say i have a java project setup in eclipse. i have all the thirdparty jar's and reading the resources etc set in the eclipse IDE.
ie all the classpath etc are set through the IDE

Now if i want to launch my app from commandline.

Can i get some hints/ links where i can undersand the configuration settings that can be done in Unix / windows machine to launch the application.

Looking for runtime configuration settings.

Because in production environment there is no IDE involved?

Also How do i set classpath in the server say jboss?

Answer (score 3):

You can include the classpath and dependencies info in the Manifest of your application.

And in addition, you can consider [ant](http://ant.apache.org/) if you want to be able to build your project on a machine without an IDE at all.

Is there any information that you specify in Eclipse and you need to use in your production env?

Comment: Hi am looking more info on setting up the runtime environment for the project.

Answer (score 1):

Use Eclipse 3.5

Create a launch configuration by selecting your class containing the main method, and running it.

File -> Export -> Java -> Runnable Jar

Personally I like the "put libraries in a sub-folder" since that does not merge jars or use a custom classloader.

The generated jar file can be executed with "java -jar whatever.jar".

You can redo this easier by either generating an ant script or making the launch configuration a shared file.
(Run -> Run configurations.  Select launch configuration,  Choose "Common" pane.  Choose "Shared file" and select a place to put it.